# Remove pie chart from canvas and replace with another pie chart

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts, html5-canvas

Im using chart.js to create a doughnut chart in the canvas

Code:

```
            var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);

            var PieData = [
              {
                  value: 700,
                  color: "#f56954",
                  highlight: "#f56954",
                  label: "Chrome"
              },
              {
                  value: 500,
                  color: "#00a65a",
                  highlight: "#00a65a",
                  label: "IE"
              },
              {
                  value: 400,
                  color: "#f39c12",
                  highlight: "#f39c12",
                  label: "FireFox"
              },
              {
                  value: 600,
                  color: "#00c0ef",
                  highlight: "#00c0ef",
                  label: "Safari"
              },
              {
                  value: 300,
                  color: "#3c8dbc",
                  highlight: "#3c8dbc",
                  label: "Opera"
              },
              {
                  value: 100,
                  color: "#d2d6de",
                  highlight: "#d2d6de",
                  label: "Navigator"
              }
            ];
            var pieOptions = {
                segmentShowStroke: true,
                segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
                segmentStrokeWidth: 1,
                percentageInnerCutout: 50, 
                animationSteps: 100,
                animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
                animateRotate: true,
                animateScale: false,
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
}

<canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
```

I want to delete the current pie chart and replace it with a new one when i click on a list item. I have tried using the destroy() method but it has had no effect

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
     <li><a href="#" onclick="">Device</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on list first you can set innerHtml empty to remove the content of the chart element like

```
document.getElementById('pieChart').innerHtml = '';
```

then draw a new chart into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pieChartCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

Of course you want to declare the canvasWidth and canvasHeight variables.